# in DBML, how to get child table with specific fields rather than all fields

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, dbml

We are using SQL Server and application is developed with **DBML**. Now due to the functionality of eager loading I am having an issue. I have a **table A** which have relationship with **table B**. (*A -> B*). Now when I try to load table A, it will get all fields of table B. Culprit is such that table B is having 2-3 columns which is very heavy, contains `byte array` data and due to those column it takes too much load for getting data of table A also.

**Question** 
Can I have such way that I can load only few columns (not all columns) of table B when I am getting table A?

**What I have tried**
I am getting this error :

> The expression specified must be of the form p.A, where p is the
>   parameter and A is a property or field member.

when I tried with below code -

```
DataContext2.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<A>(x => x.Campaign);
options.LoadWith<A>(x => x.AnotherTable);
options.LoadWith<A>(x => x.B.Select(o => new B
{
    Id = o.Id,
    Name = o.Name,
    Person = o.Person,
}).ToList());
DataContext2.LoadOptions = options;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `join` and `select` only necessary columns:

```
var yourQuery = (from t_A in dbContext.Table_A
             join t_B in dbContext.Table_B on t_A.ID equals t_B.ID                 
             //use where operator to filter rows
             select new {
                 Id = t_B.Id,
                 Name = t_B.Name,
                Person = t_B.Person
                  // any field you want from your query
             }).ToList();
```